# How to parse a user's input and store each individual character as a string

Tags: c++, string, parsing, vector, char

Okay so I'm working a calculator program that takes in a user input(ex. "(3+(4+12))"), and I need to parse the user's input and store it in an array of strings but I am having trouble doing so. My code currently is this

```
void parseInput(string input) {
 vector <string> input_vector;

 for(int i = 0; i < input.size(); ++i) {
    if(isdigit(input.at(i)) == 0 && isdigit(input.at(i + 1)) == 0) {
        ++i;
        input_vector.push_back((input.at(i) + input.at(i+1)));
    }
    else {
        input_vector.push_back(input.at(i));
    }
 }

 for(int i = 0; i < input_vector.size(); ++i) {
    cout << endl << input_vector[i];
 } 
}
```

I know my problem is coming from trying to add a char to an vector of strings, but how would I get each char in the string and keep it as a string to store into my vector. Or is there a better way to parse this out??

### edit

Okay so what I am having the most trouble with is the problems that come from the 12 splitting up into two separate chars "1 * 2" How would I go about so that it represents 12 and doesn't split it up???

Comment: If you're using C++11 you can simply add an extra pair of braces in the `push_back` expressions, i.e. `input_vector.push_back({input.at(i)});`, `std::string` has an `initialiser_list` constructor.

Answer (score 0):

### **Here is a solution (using c++11):**

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

#include <iostream>

int main() {

  std::string const input = "(3+(4+12))";

  std::vector<std::string> chars(input.length());

  // Maps each character of `input` to `std::string`
  // with that character and saves the results in
  // corresponding position in `chars` vector:
  std::transform(input.cbegin(), input.cend(), chars.begin(),
    [](char c) {
      // One of the ways to cast `char` to `std::string`:
      return std::string(1, c);
    });

  // To be sure it works properly, it prints
  // generated strings: 
  for (size_t i = 0; i < chars.size(); ++i) {
    std::cout << chars[i];
  }
  std::cout << std::endl;

}
```

Comment: Problem with this is that it still separates the 12 into two separate chars.

Comment: @looseyjoosey because you'v write that you need to **store each individual character as a string**. `"12"` is not a character, it's a `'1'` character following by `'2'` character. They are individual. That's why my solution separates  them. To avoid it, you need to parse expression into tokens.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is u need to split the string into tokens, i have given an example which will add 4 to 12, to make it 16, but think that the string does'nt have any brackets, suppose if the user entered 4+12 and u need to add it you can do the following:

```
char string[10], nstr[10];
int p=0, a=0, b=0, op=0;
cin>>string; // input string
While (string[i]!='+' || string[i]!='-')
{
nstr[p]=string[i]; // copy the contents of string to nstr.
p++;
i++;
}// loop exits if the string[i] reaches to the operator (+/-*).
nstr[p]='\0';
a=atoi(nstr);// convert the string to integer.
op=i;// this will hold the position of array of the operator in the string.
i++;
p=0;
while (string[i]!='\0')
{
nstr[p]=string[i];// this will copy the contents of the string after the operator.
i++;
p++;
}
nstr[p]='\0';
b=atoi(nstr);
if (string[op]=='+')// check what the user want to do. Add/subtract/divide etc.
c=a+b;
else if (string[op]=='-')
c=a-b;
```

This program is not tested but will work, if not then use the logic in your program, like i did in my program, this will not take 1 and 2 sepratly, instead it will take 4 and 12, you can type more charaters but is limited to long, i used int here to get the return value of atoi(), hope this helps u...

Comment: The indentation is horrible.